# dependent: :destroy doesn't work (has_many association)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My problem is as simple as is the title of this thread
i have two classes

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :subcategories, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subcategories

end

class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

but when i hit `link_to "Delete", category_path(category), method: :delete` requested category gets destroyed, but all subcategories stay like nothing happened.

EDIT

Server Log:

```
Started DELETE "/categories/8" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-29 01:38:01 +0100
Processing by CategoriesController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"rOTo3ROv/QsQRMPyCljbMvrViKgihC1CowBdlHdq7O4=", "id"=>"8"}
  Category Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE `categories`.`id` = 8 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.5ms)  DELETE FROM `categories` WHERE `categories`.`id` = 8
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/categories
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)


Started GET "/categories" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-29 01:38:01 +0100
Processing by CategoriesController#index as HTML
  Category Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `categories`.* FROM `categories`
  Rendered categories/index.html.haml within layouts/application (0.9ms)
  Rendered application/_header.html.haml (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 5.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Comment: Can you post your application server log? What does it show, when you delete a category?

Comment: we would need to see the controller code you're calling to delete the category.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you calling `delete` on category?  you should call `destroy` instead.

Comment: this is likely the cause. `delete` will skip all ActiveRecord-related callbacks (which includes the dependency management), whereas `destroy` will not.

Comment: Seems like a common mistake made by novices